# Which Javascript Toolkit Degrades Most Gracefully?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, toolkit

I've looked through many Javascript toolkits.

Each of them have different strengths, but all of them seem to be missing a usable backup solution if Javascript fails or is turned off.

So I'm looking for the Javascript toolkit/framework that has the best backup method when Javascript fails.

====

For example:

I'd like to have a simple AJAX request, that loads data into a DIV on click.

But if Javascript fails or is turned off, I want to have some kind of alternative way for users to access that content.

I could use PHP, but that would involve developing each feature twice... Is this is the only way?

Comment: By definition, you can't use Javascript if it's turned off... What sort of backup solution do you mean?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll add a usage example to my question.

Comment: How your application behaves without javascript can't depend by a javascript framework. It's all in your implementation of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a lot of JavaScript code, you can reuse it on the server side using node.js framework, if your objective is to write code only once and run it wherever you want. Node.js is server side JavaScript that can run your client-side code on the server-side. You client-side code will run on server-side with little or no modification as per node.js folks. As far as your Ajax call go... Those should also work just fine, at least in theory, according what I have heard of about node.js. When you run your client-side Ajax code on server-side and that Ajax code contains a "get" request, the node.js framework loads the requested data from the file system (a file or db or xml or whatever) and returns the data set normally as if the request actually came from a client-side call. While I have not written any code to test it, there are a few examples of it on the developer.yahoo.com. Disclaimer: I don't work for Yahoo or have any association with any company that promotes Yahoo.

Comment: Thank you for the concise answer! --- I had already learned about Node.js from galambalazs' answer, but he used some terminology I wasn't familiar with. --- Your answer was easy to understand and directly related to my problem, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You should build your application as simple html which would work without js. And only then js should be implemented. In this case you'll have usable application event without js support.

Comment: The problem with this method, is that it runs into the "flash of unstyled content" issue. ---- This is somewhat confusing---especially for people on slow conenctions, who will see the unstyled content for a longer period of time.

Comment: You can have 2 different versions. If js is detected in frontpage you can redirect users to js enabled site.

Comment: True, but for a large site with many pages, maintaining two versions could be tedious...  Is this the only way to avoid the F.O.U.C.?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is an **awesome** language. In fact, you can effectively use it on the server-side with [**Node.js**](http://nodejs.org/). Now with **[jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom)** you can actually copy your client-side code and generate whole page **on the server**.

@davglass at the YUI team did some amazing work, intergrating client-side modules on the server.

- [Node.js, YUI 3 & Dom Manipulation… Oh My!](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/04/09/node-js-yui-3-dom-manipulation-oh-my/)
- [Video: Dav Glass — Using Node.js and YUI 3](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/theater/video.php?v=glass-node)
- [nodejs-yui3 on github](https://github.com/davglass/nodejs-yui3)

You can see that almost all YUI component can run on the server-side as a **fallback**.
e.g.: [datatabe](http://express.davglass.com/datatable), [calendar](http://express.davglass.com/calendar/), [tabview](http://express.davglass.com/tabview?tab=1)

Comment: Sever-side Javascript is a intriguing concept. But doesn't this ruin the whole concept of bandwidth-saving through client-side scripting?

Comment: What makes it exciting is that you can use the same code to generate content on the server-side. You only need to write everything once, as you stated in your question.

Comment: But would node.js work with AJAX calls for data? --- Referring to my example above; could I have that data also appear without client-side Javascript via node.js?

Comment: The way it looks like is that the non-js user gets a whole new page mutated according to the click event, while js enabled users experience the usual interaction without server-side tricks. Again it acts as a fallback.